# IF statement in php Retains answer from previous run

Tags: java, php, if-statement

I Have the following code.

```
$Case_Answer = 99.999;

$Compile = exec('javac Main.java');

if ((exec('java Main')) == $Case_Answer){
echo "Correct";}
else 
echo "Incorrect";
```

My problem results when I run the script several times.

If I run this php script with all correct values and making sure that Main.java compiles. Everything works well.

When I run it a second time after modifying Main.java so it does not compile correctly. The if statement will execute whatever it did the previous run. I need it to refresh every time and it cause a problem. 
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: So if the second compile fails it still has the previous compiled version yes?  Then you may need to delete the working copy before compiling again.

Comment: Check your spelling Line 3 : `javac Main.java`     Line 5: `java Main`

Comment: Thank you very much @AbraCadaver . After all all this i had 2 lines.

1 to delete the Main.java and the other to rewrite Main.java to original state

I totally forgot to erase the class from the previous execution that still existed. Thank you.

Comment: @phil652 that is not a problem. 'javac' compiles and 'java' runs the class

Comment: If that was it mark accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If the first compile is successful and the second compile fails it still has the previous good compiled version to that runs yes? Then you may need to delete the working file before compiling again.

I'm not a Java guy so I will assume that the compiled Java file is called `Main`:

```
$Case_Answer = 99.999;

if(file_exists('Main')) { // delete it here
    unlink('Main');
}
$Compile = exec('javac Main.java');

if ((exec('java Main')) == $Case_Answer){
    echo "Correct";
} else  {
    echo "Incorrect";
}
```

Even if the second compile would otherwise be successful, won't it fail if the file exists from a previous compile?